# Excel file is opening in courrpted format

Tags: excel, format

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FobZw.png --> MY PROBLEM IMAGE LINK.

When I open my excel file it show like the above image.

And something like this --> "Äª$Ðìº<†i¹×’ZÜ`IÒ™¢Z¤Ã@F“Xa.ÿH‘Î’ÜvV,ÔP¡Å[|ÕõØÌ$€×w¼kRåKÙ}"

Comment: Unzip it and check to make sure it’s actually an Excel file. There should be a bunch of XML documents in the zip file.

Comment: @Skin what I have to unzip.

Comment: Rename the extension of the file to .zip and open it. My suggestion would be to create a new workbook with some data so you can compare the structures of the XML. It’ll only slightly help but should still help in some way.

Comment: @Skin It is showing MY FILE PATH and then the archive is either in unknown or damaged format.

Comment: @Skin I tried it in another worksheet then it is working

Comment: Yep, so it’s corrupt.

Comment: @Skin So now I can nothing???

Comment: @Skin I have opened the zip file.

Comment: But there is no file.